# PHP echo function doesn't work

Tags: php, echo

Very simple code, but it would't echo the name of the chosen submitted file, furthermore, some browsers display it as source code. I'd appreciate the explanation.

```
<?php

echo $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
?>

<form action = "Upload.php"  method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
<input type = "submit" name = "Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: What's outputted if you do `var_dump($_FILES);` above your echo?

Comment: Cant replicate it works, check if PHP is installed or you have .php extension for the filename.

Comment: Cant replicated either, but that a very bad way of printing anything.

Answer (score 3):

> some browsers display it as source code

PHP, in this context, is a server side programming lanugage. You either:

- Are not testing with a web server
- Do not have PHP installed on your server
- Do not have your server configured to run PHP for the file containing your PHP code

Make sure that:

- You have a PHP capable web server installed
- The PHP file has a `.php` file extension
- `Upload.php` is the file containing the code in the question
- You are accessing the file through an `http://` URI and not `file://` URI

Answer (score 0):

I tried you code as it is and it worked fine.

Looks like your PHP is not being interpreted .
Create a page Please run phpinfo().

```
<?php
phpinfo()
?>
```

Check if mod_php5 is enabled. Generally this is the module which allows Apache to interpret PHP files

Or you could check in apache conf file as well(http.conf)

Thanks,
Sambhav

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you expect echo to work once the form is submitted.
So, you must receive output of following:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
}
?>
```